# How to observe mobx observables outside the render function in react?

Tags: reactjs, mobx-react

I have a mobx store

```
class MyStore {
    @observable
    public myvariable = ""
```

and a view which should update its data when the `myvariable` value changed

```
@inject("myStore")
@observer
class MyView extends React.Component<any, any> {
    @observable
    public mydata;

    // inside this class I have to know if `myvariable` value changed
    // if it does, I have to fetch some data to assign to `mydata` so
    // that I can render that new data
```

I don't want to put the `mydata` in the store, since I have a lot of views, each with different types of data that can be updated if the `myvariable` value changed. I only want to update `mydata` of the view I am currently showing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
    if(prevProps.myStore.myvariable !== this.props.myStore.myvariable){
        // update mydata
    }
}
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Comment: so simple. I missed the componentDidUpdate. Thanks